# JavaScript Looping Variables on Left Side of Equal Sign

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through results and writing them out to html.

I want to increment the number 1 on the lest side of the equal sign - the binding -
 A_Inside_Bus_1_div, A_Inside_Bus_2_div, A_Inside_Bus_3_div etc..

How should I go about that?

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
   A_Inside_Bus_1_div.innerText = i + ". " + snapshot.child("0/A_Inside_Bus " + i).val();
   A_Inside_Bus_1_Comments_div.innerText = snapshot.child("0/A_Inside_Bus " + i + " Comments").val();
            }
```

Comment: Don't. Dynamically accessing variables is a terrible habit. Stick everything into a list, then just index the list.

Comment: Ok can you provide an example. Not sure I understand how to do that.

Comment: Writing an answer now. My fingers are frozen, so it's slow going.

Comment: NO probs thank you.

Comment: Any time you think you need variable variables, you should be using either an array or an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
var A_Inside_Bus_div = [];
var A_Inside_Bus_Comments_div = [];
```

Before you continue the rest, like editing `.innerHTML`, you need to create those objects. Only after that you can do something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    A_Inside_Bus_div[i].innerText = i + ". " + snapshot.child("0/A_Inside_Bus " + i).val();
    A_Inside_Bus_Comments_div[i].innerText = snapshot.child("0/A_Inside_Bus " + i + " Comments").val();
            }
```

This is just an idea how you "should go" about that, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Trying to make variable names to do what you're trying to do just leads to needlessly messy code down the road.

Stick all your elements into arrays:

```
var elems = [
    A_Inside_Bus_1_div
    A_Inside_Bus_2_div
    ... 
];

var comments = [
    A_Inside_Bus_1_Comments_div
    A_Inside_Bus_2_Comments_div
    ... 
];
```

Then just index the arrays:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
   elems[i].innerText = i + ". " + snapshot.child("0/A_Inside_Bus " + i).val();
   comments[i].innerText = snapshot.child("0/A_Inside_Bus " + i + " Comments").val();
}
```

This is an example of how you could do it with your current setup. Note though, it could be cleaned up. If each element of the `elems` array always has a partner in `comments`, it would make more sense to group them together in an object, and only have 1 array.

Also note that populating the arrays in a loop makes more sense. I just hardcoded the arrays here for the sake of brevity. I'm not sure how you're creating the elements originally. They should probably be created and put straight into the array instead of naming them and adding them later.

Comment: Thanks for all the great suggestions everybody :)

Answer (score 1):

If those variables are actually the IDs of DIVsm and you're depending on the fact that IDs are turned into global varables, you can use `document.getElementById()` to access them.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
   document.getElementById('A_Inside_Bus_' + (i+1) + '_div').innerText = i + ". " + snapshot.child("0/A_Inside_Bus " + i).val();
   document.getElementById('A_Inside_Bus_' + (i+1) + '_Comments_div').innerText = snapshot.child("0/A_Inside_Bus " + i + " Comments").val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you could go about doing this, but they tend to involve some pretty bad habits, like using [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) or attaching variables to the global object so you can access them with a string:

```
var a = 1;
window['a']; //1
```

But there are better alternatives, the most common is probably storing them in equal-length arrays:

```
var divs = [div1, div2, div3];
var items = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish'];

items.forEach(function(element, index){
    divs[index].innerText = items[i];
});
```

You could also look at building out a single array of objects:

```
var objects = [{div: div1, item: 'cat'}, {div: div2, item: 'dog'}, {div: div3, item: 'fish'}];

for object in objects {
    object.div.innerText = object.item;
}
```